# Create hidden cmd javascript

Tags: javascript, cmd

I'm looking for a way to run a cmd command without showing the cmd window to the user.

I'm using something like:

```
    
    function reboot()  {
          var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
          ws.Exec("shutdown.exe -r -t 120");

    }
```

But it still shows the window, is there anyway not to show it?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to shut down the users computer without them knowing, what a great idea!

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things... or a bigger JavaScript sandbox.

Comment: I _hope_ that he's referring to a standalone WSH script, not a browser.

Comment: @Zifre I just had an actual *laugh out loud* moment

Comment: It was a request by a lot of users for a Shutdown Program I am making, this is used for a sidebar gadget so the user can do a timed shutdown from the sidebar

Comment: @Sandeep Bansal: sorry, I figured there probably were some valid uses, but I couldn't think of any at the time and your question didn't say why you wanted to do this. This is one of those questions where it's a good idea to be very clear about your intentions so you don't come across as malicious. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28VS.85%29.aspx) function instead of `Exec` and pass it 0 as the second argument to prevent it showing the command prompt window:

```
ws.Run("shutdown.exe -r -t 120", 0);
```

The System Shutdown window will still be displayed (I don't think there is any way to suppress that).

Comment: Like so C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe "javascript:new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').Run('cmd /c start /max C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe',0,false);close()"

Answer (score 1):

You can make the window minimized using the following command:

```
cmd /c start /min SomeCommand
```

I assume that you're aware that this won't work in a browser, and I therefore assume that you're writing a standalone JScript file with WSH.

Comment: Well it's through a sidebar gadget therefore running from IE so it is a browser, a bit difficult to do.